# Android activity is leaked when touching a view in the Volley response callback. Any idea or solution?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-volley

I'm using Android Studio 1.5 to detect activity leaks. I have a simple VolleyRequest :

```
VolleyRequestManager.getRequestQueue().add(new CustomRequest(new Response.Listener<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(final Response response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }));
```

This way no leaks happen, as expected.

But when i touch a view in the onResponse callback like :

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(final Response response) {
    findViewById(R.id.container).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

The activity will leak!!

Note: I'm using Volley 1.0.19 and this issue only happen on pre-lollipop devices.

Comment: Can you post the content of `container` (layout file). My project uses `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'` with a `LinearLayout` contaning a `TextView`. AS is 1.4. It works normally

Answer (score 0):

The reason of `Activity` leak is that you keep a `Activity` reference in  `Response.Listener`, when your Activity finished, the request is still executing in background, and than the `Activity` leak...

The first solution is that keep an `Activity` reference in `Response.Listener`, and set it to null when you finish Activity(in onDestory method).

The second: Use `EventBus`. Register `successEvent` in your Activity, and post an `successEvent(with response data)` in `onResponse` method.

Comment: the request is already finished, i update a view and after that i quit the activity.

Comment: anyway, the first solution makes no sense, the second might work, but the project is already to complex, and i don't want to include another library

Comment: Cancel all request in `onDestory` method.